# How can I multiply binary image t rgb image in python?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, computer-vision

oI have a binary image which is the segmented form of another color image .

As you know, a binary image is 2-d but an RGB image is 3-d, how can I multiply them together? please hope

Comment: If the images are stored as NumPy arrays, just multiply. NumPy does broadcasting.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your image and mask to numpy arrays.
Element-wise multiplication with numpy arrays can simply be done without any special treatment. For example:

```
a = np.random.randint(0,10,(3,2,2)) # RGB of size 2x2
b = np.random.randint(0,2,(2,2))    # Binary mask of size 2x2
c = a*b
```

Output:

```
a = array([ [[7, 6],
             [5, 8]],

            [[1, 3],
             [8, 5]],

            [[1, 8],
             [4, 4]]])

b = array(  [[1, 0],
             [0, 1]])

c = array([ [[7, 0],
             [0, 8]],

            [[1, 0],
             [0, 5]],

            [[1, 0],
             [0, 4]]])
```